# Manipulate awk arguments in gnuplot

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I use awk and it's output inside gnuplot to plot data from a file. This works as follows in gnuplot:

```
s=`awk '{N+=$2}; END {print N}' modes/10.dat`
```

In gnuplot I can then work with `s`. However I would like to pass the argument to awk from the gnuplot code, like:

```
i=10
file='modes/'.i.'.dat'
s=`awk '{N+=$2}; END {print N}' file`
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I also tried sth. like:

```
i=10
file='modes/'.i.'.dat'    
cmd = sprintf("awk '{N+=$2}; END {print N}' %s", file)
s=`cmd`
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
s = system(cmd)
```

to evaluate the shell expression contained in the gnuplot variable `cmd`:

```
i = 10
file = 'modes/'.i.'.dat'    
cmd = sprintf("awk '{N+=$2}; END {print N}' %s", file)
s = system(cmd)
```